# Optimize performance when adding many views to layout

Tags: java, android

I am using this library (https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) to create my views and adding them to linearlayou with addView() method.

My problem is that I have many views to add (sometimes even more than 200) and using addView() method is slow.

I have already read some info about lazyloading listviews. But my parent layout is not listview, because my children views are quite different.

Is there any way how to optimize performace of adding views to my parent linearlayout? Or any other approach?
(loading items from database is effective and is not part of issue)

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of view do you add? Actually it's hard to give an advise without any sample of your code. There are two base problems: too many views and too complex view.

Comment: The view is quite complex. It has about 3 textviews included and one image (that is already loaded lazy). I suppose when I use lazyloading and load only visible views it could be ok. But I am only finding listview lazyloading examples.